# Partial Derivative / Multivariable Chain Rule Notation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, chain-rule

**Example 1.**

w = $x^2 +y^2 + z^2$

x = $uv$

y = $ucos(v)$

z = $ usin(v)$

> Using chain rule, find $\frac{∂w}{∂u}$

I understand partial derivatives and how to take chain rule for multivariable functions but why does $\frac{∂w}{∂u}$imply the same meaning as $\frac{∂w∘f}{∂u}$ where$ f(u,v) = (x,y,z)$

Comment: What is g and f ?

Comment: sorry edited...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you write “w” (and implicitly are thinking of x, y and z as functions of u and v) you are already thinking of $w \circ f$. No difference between the two.